# Programmatically Aligning Elements in Monotouch View

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, alignment

I've created a view that will need to be added to several different screens. I'm struggling to figure out how to align the elements correctly in the view.

The output needs to look like the following:

[image]

I've tried the following with no success:

```
var uiiv = new UIImageView(image);
var firstLine = new UITextField { Text = description};
var secondLine = new UITextField { Text = summary};
this.Add(uiiv);
this.Add(firstLine );
this.Add(secondLine );
```

Comment: Odd, you are not passing the frame to any of those constructors.  You should be using new UIImageView (RectangleF) ctor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every UI element should have a Frame property that allows you to specify the position of the element relative to it's parent view.  Using this property will allow you to position the element.